# Query table update automatically in excel

Tags: sql, excel, vba, vbscript

I have access to an SQL database with a specific table that I need in Excel.
Through Excel, I have created a table that has access to this table.
What I want is to make a server update the SQL query table in Excel at 2 a.m. so the Excel file always has the newest data each morning.

I have created a VBSscript that I can run through Task Scheduler at a given time. The VBScript looks like this:

```
Dim xlApp
Dim xlBook

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\XX.ZZ\Desktop\Book4.xlsm")
xlApp.Run "Sample"
xlBook.Save
xlBook.Close
xlApp.Quit

Set xlBook = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing
```

The VBScript runs the macro called "Sample" I want to create a macro that updates this SQL Query Table and have tried with:

```
Public Sub Sample()
'
' Sample Macro
'
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

End Sub
```

But it has not worked so far. Any suggestions?

FYI, the server is always on, but I am not logged on when the code is running. Should this matter?

Update, I have tried running the VBScript manually, and after a couple of minutes the tables will actually be updated. So I don't thing the macro is wrong? But more the fact that Windows does not give it enough time to perform the task?

Comment: try WScript.Sleep() before it's saved and closed?

Comment: how should the coding be then if I want it to run for 10 minutes?
`Dim xlApp`
`Dim xlBook`

`Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")`
`Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\XX.ZZ\Desktop\Book4.xlsm")`
`xlApp.Run "Sample"`
`WScript.Sleep(600000)`
`xlBook.Save`
`xlBook.Close`
`xlApp.Quit`

`Set xlBook = Nothing`
`Set xlApp = Nothing`

Comment: I forgot to tag you, @ergonaut

Comment: did that work @KhalidN?